# Kdb ema function for irregular time series

Tags: kdb

In kdb, an ema function is already provided which works fine for regular time series.

However for irregular time series, does anyone have an ema function implemented for that?

I think I am suppose to use ternary accumulators but can't seem to get it to work.

Edit:
I am trying to implement as per this youtube link (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22pT7rGbEv8) whereby the author provided the python version (https://github.com/stakewithus/notes/blob/main/notebook/ema.ipynb).
The weightings change depending on the delta time.

Comment: The ema function doesn't care about time, it takes whatever values you pass it and it weights/decays them. But can you give examples of what you mean by irregular time series and why ema doesn't work for it? Please supply a numerical example and what you expect the output to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in `ema` function does take a list of decay rates (alphas) as well as accepting a single fixed decay rate. For a fixed rate:

```
/uniform alpha=0.25 (aka .75 weight to previous EMA)
q)ema[.25;10 20 30 40 50]
10 12.5 16.875 22.65625 29.49219

q)(.75*10)+.25*20
12.5
q)(.75*12.5)+.25*30
16.875
/etc
```

and for a non-uniform decay rate

```
q)show alphas:0.5 xexp 4?4.0
0.2873888 0.9621388 0.1377848 0.5829307
q)ema[1f,alphas;10 20 30 40 50]
10 12.87389 29.35159 30.81877 42.0001

q)((1-0.2873888)*10)+0.2873888*20
12.87389   /most weight to previous ma
q)((1-0.9621388)*12.87389)+0.9621388*30
29.35158   /most weight to new value
/etc
```

The challenge for you then is how to translate your irregularly timed data into the `alphas`. In my example above I just picked 4 random values between 0 and 4.0 (`4?4.0`) but in your case it wouldn't be random.

Answer (score 0):

What I figured:

```
.namespace.halflife: 00:00:02;  
table: update emaIrregular:{(y*(1-xexp[0.5;(z%.namespace.halflife)%1e9]))+(x*xexp[0.5;(z%.namespace.halflife)%1e9])}\\[first price;price;deltas time] from table;
```